# SQL ordering in XCode

Tags: sql, xcode

I want to order the data by variables and then select the first record. But it doesn't work. Here is my code:

```
NSString *s = [db stringForQuery:@"SELECT cardInfo.?, cardInfo.?, cardInfo.? FROM cardInfo WHERE cardInfo.currentBalance > ? ORDER BY cardInfo.? DESC, cardInfo.? DESC, cardInfo.? ASC ", first, second, third, [NSNumber numberWithDouble:money], first, second, third];
```

if I change it into ordering by constants, it works.

```
NSString *s = [db stringForQuery:@"SELECT a, b, c FROM cardInfo WHERE cardInfo.currentBalance > ? ORDER BY a DESC, b DESC, c ASC ",[NSNumber numberWithDouble:money]];
```

Does anyone know how to correct it?
Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

Yep.  `ORDER BY cardInfo.?` attempts to parameterize the metadata, the column name.  Prepared statements allow you to parameterize the *data* only.

You can say

```
where tablename.colname = ?
```

You cannot say

```
where ?.colname = 'foo'
```

HTH.

Answer (score 0):

I have solved this problem. I replace ? with %@  and it works

```
[db stringForQuery:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"SELECT cardInfo.%@, cardInfo.%@, cardInfo.%@ FROM cardInfo WHERE cardInfo.currentBalance > %@ ORDER BY cardInfo.%@, cardInfo.%@,cardInfo.%@ ", first, second,third,  [NSNumber numberWithDouble:money], first, second, third]];
```